# Question regarding variable index notation in mathematical modeling

Tags: mathematical-modeling

I have a mathematical model, where the following variables are used:

- $x_i$,
- $x_{i,i}$ and
- $x_{i, j}$, $i \neq j$.

There is a need to express these variables with just one variable, using a "wildcard" character in the index of the variable that could denote any of the above cases.

For example, I could define $x_{i\_}$ to denote either $x_i$, $x_{i,i}$ or $x_{i,j}$.

I understand that there is not a standard way to do this, and it would be fine as long as I define it properly, but I would like to use a notation that would not cause any confusion. Traditionally, in computer programming, a wildcard character is either "*" or "%", but I believe these characters could cause confusion in the particular context. Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: There exists already the multiindex notation. Let $I=(i_1, \cdots,i_k)$ than you can write $x_I=x_{(i_1,\cdots,i_k)}$. This Is useful for e.g. the [Einstein notation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)